What exactly is the role of a business analyst in proposing solutions to business problems?
I am learning business analysis theory and I am confused about the extent to which the BA proposes the solution to the business problem.
I understand that business analysis is generally defined as the practice of identifying business problems and then proposing solutions (I realise there's more to it than that, but this is the bit I'm interested in). However having completed a couple of Udemy courses on business analysis fundamentals I have found that these courses stop after describing the process of eliciting, analysing, and finalising requirements - they don't seem to cover the "proposed solutions" side of things.
One of the courses I listened to did mention that it is not the role of a business analyst to provide technical specifications (e.g. around IT infrastructure), that is the job of the systems analyst. But it would be useful to see a concrete example, so I can understand the point at which a high level BA solution is then handed on to someone else to elaborate/implement.
what constitutes the point at which a business analyst has successfully "proposed a solution"?
It would be great if this could be explained within example, ideally in an IT Project since that is the space I work in. i.e. for a given set of requirements for an IT project, what would the BA's proposed solution look like? Is it just the requirements? And if not, what form does it take? What part of the proposed solution is the responsibility of the BA and what is the responsibility of other team members (e.g. systems analyst)?
Thank you!

Business Analysis principally involves understanding, describing and proposing the functional aspects of the solution but usually not the technical implementation of that functionality. So a BA might specify what customer interactions are required, what information is needed at each point, any calculations and other processing that should be performed, but typically would not be expected to make decisions about what technologies to use or what code to write.
Most software development tends to happen in a more or less iterative and collaborative way however. A BA may well be part of the conversation about the technology; the technical architect and developers often get involved in discussions about business functionality. Don't think of it in terms of "handing over" or "finalising" a proposal because that's not often the way things work. Nothing is "final" before it is implemented and tested and proven in practice. Some things are never finished until you eventually stop using them (perhaps several years hence) and throw them away.

That's great context thanks @nvogel. makes sense, & I'm keen to understand with a concrete example. Does this sound broadly right for an agile project to build a dashboard:

BA gathers requirements about info/visuals the dashboard should contain + non-functional stuff (refresh schedule etc.)
BA creates requirements documentation, which for agile might be user stories, wireframes, acceptance criteria
Tech SMEs (eg system analyst) take requirements and design solution (database design & tech used to build dashboard) with BA support
Sprints start, product is built iteratively


@jay what you describe seems a bit too sequential. A more lean and agile approach would be to perform 1,2,3 and 4 continuously and in parallel. i.e. identify and prioritise some key deliverables; do analysis and design just ahead of building and testing; get feedback; then repeat. If you take a Scrum approach then the BA ought to be part of the Scrum team and the BAs work done within sprints.

Thanks again @nvogel, that also makes sense. I understand that in practice things are typically collaborative and iterative, but for the sake of me being clear on BA responsibilities - if you had to delineate the BAs deliverables on a project (an individual scrum sprint, or a full waterfall project) from those of the devs/architect, what would they be? Just the requirements (in whatever form those took), or also some elements of the solution design? I know I'm nitpicking here but keen to get very clear on the BA role vs other team members, at least in theory even if not in practice.

@jay The classic answer would be that the BA is responsible for requirements not for design. In reality it's often impossible to separate those two things without making life very difficult for everyone.
